# How to minify inline javascript with Python

Tags: javascript, python, inline, minify

The answers that I get only cover .js files but I need to minify something like this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (e)
    {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

To this:

```
<script>window.addEventListener('load',function(e){...});</script>
```

Actually I use "htmlmin" to minify the HTML code before I write the files with it but the inline javascripts remain with the original format.

Any help what to do here? Maybe a new package to replace "htmlmin". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use inline scripts, problem solved.

Comment: You are right but the inline javascript call functions that run only in that file, not the whole website. ;-)

Comment: There are a million other ways to do that without using inline scripts. Some day you're going to have a bug, in production, and spend an embarrassing amount of time figuring out that the undescriptive stack trace is being generated from an inline script. Friends don't let friends use inline scripts. They don't generate good stack traces, they're opaque to your tools (as you've discovered), they pollute the global namespace unless your careful, depending on your editor they may not play nice with auto indent/syntax highlighting, they can run afoul of CSPs, just not worth it.

Comment: OK, this script activate some actions on my personal blog: 
            window.addEventListener('load',function(e)
            {
                bloggen.hscrollTables();
                bloggen.switchButtons();
            });

Comment: Besides that, it also the Disqus and Analytics for each page. Disqus need an specific config por each file. Tell me how to deal with it. :-)

Comment: Analytics (if we're talking google analytics) comes pre-minified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using REST API from the site https://www.minifier.org/.

Disclaimer: The site is made by user @matthiasmullie 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/802993/matthiasmullie

Example here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = 'https://minify.minifier.org/'

data = """<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (e)
    {
        i = 4;
    });
    </script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
script = soup.select_one('script')
r = requests.post(url, data={"source":script.text, "type" :"js"})
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
script.clear()
script.append(json_data['minified'])

print(script)
```

It prints:

```
<script>window.addEventListener('load',function(e)
{i=4})</script>
```

Comment: That help me a lot. Pity it is a library in PHP to import locally.